# Sorting posts that has a meta value first then the rest of the posts

Tags: pre-get-posts

Im using the **pre_get_posts** hook to customize my query for a custom post type archive.

Some of the posts for this custom post type have a meta key **mp_micropub_accredited** with the meta value of **1** and others don't have this meta key set.

I use the following code,

```
function micropubs_filter_posts( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'micropubs' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
        $accredited = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'orderby', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ); 
        if ( empty( $accredited ) )
            return;
        if ( $accredited === 'accredited' ) {
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'mp_micropub_accredited' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'micropubs_filter_posts' );
```

So when i locate to this address in my browser it displays only the posts with the meta key set and no other posts.

```
http://localhost/site/post-type-archive/?orderby=accredited
```

How is it possible to include all the other posts that don't have the **mp_micropub_accredited** meta key set but are displayed after the ones that are?

Your help much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you when you are updating meta values with 1 update rest with 0.
I mean set the key in all posts with 1 or 0 to avoid the complex query.

You can still do it with a simple script. It will check if key doesn't exist then update it with 0. So your current code will work like charm.

**OR**

You can use `compare` with `NOT EXISTS`

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'mp_micropub_accredited',
        'value' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'mp_micropub_accredited',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    )
);
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
```

**Note:** This solution will only work with WP >= 3.9 as `NOT EXISTS` only works with 3.5 and greater and there was a bug with `NOT EXISTS` which has been fixed in 3.9!

Comment: Brilliant! I ended up setting the rest of the posts with 0. Perfect! Thankyou :)